# React Wont Caching Results of API request in Local storage

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I'm trying to build a very simple `component` in `react` that requests an image from an API and subsequently stores / caches it for any other request in the application when that component is used.

At the moment, the component ALWAYS renders, and as such - if I have the component multiple times on the page (i.e. in the first 10 results) I get multiple API calls, whereas I was expecting to only get 1 API call, with the result coming back and being stuck into `localstorage`.

Anyone any ideas? Should I be using `useMemo`, or something else? Any ideas on how to prevent the multiple API calls?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import UserService from '../../api/UserService';

const ProfileImage = () => {
   const userService  = new UserService();
   const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState();
   const cachedAvatar = localStorage.getItem('avatar');

   const mount = () => {
      console.log(cachedAvatar);

      if (cachedAvatar) {
         setAvatar(cachedAvatar);
       } else {
         userService.getUser().then((res)=>{
            setAvatar( res.avatarUrl );
            localStorage.setItem('avatar', res.avatarUrl);
         });
       }

   }

   /* unmount cleanup */
   useEffect(() => {
      mount();
   },[]);

   return (
      <img src={  avatar ? avatar : require('../../img/placeholder/avatar.png')}></img>
   );
};

export default ProfileImage;
```

Comment: put `localStorage.setItem('avatar', res.avatarUrl);` **before** `setAvatar( res.avatarUrl );` to make sure it is cached befiore rendering

Comment: @NikosM. same result 10 API calls, then the cache kicks in.

Comment: yes I see why. It is because the first time it takes some time to fetch the resource, but during this time you already render some imgs. So the solution would be to add a lifecycle hook in `componentDidMount` to then fetch and cache the request and re-render. Initially you should render with some loading.. text and have state.loading set to true. If you provide more info I can even post an answer along these lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple API calls because the avatar is fulfilled inside the localStorage only after the first call ends.
Using localStorage is not the right solution.

You need to not call the getUser every time. For example:

```
const userService = new UserService();
let getUserCall;
// create a custom hook
const useAvatar = () => {
   const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState();
   useEffect(() => {
      if (!getUserCall) {
        getUserCall = userService.getUser();
      }
      getUserCall.then(res => setAvatar(res.setAvatar))
   },[]);
   return avatar;
}
```

Then inside your component use the `useAvatar` hooks.

```
const ProfileImage = () => {
    const avatar = useAvatar();
    return (
     <img src={  avatar ? avatar : defaultAvatar  }> 
     </img>
    );
}
```